# A Python function uses constants. When are they defined? What is the usual practice?

Tags: python, pep8

A Python function defines some "constant" variables to be more readable and robust. Let's write one example.

```
def definite_calculus(x, y):
    """This is a very specific function."""
    coeff1 = 3.14**2/16
    coeff2 = 2.72//27
    return coeff1*x**2 + coeff2*x + 6*y
```

I am worried that if declare constants inside a function, the code does this declaration many times. What if the constant is very heavy like a dictionary? That would be too much work.

Question 1. When are "constant" variables declared inside a functions? Every time you run it or once? If Python creates those variables once, when "compiling" the function, how does Python know that those are "constants" and not variables that will be reassigned or overwritten?

Question 2. What is the usual Pythonic convention? Using uppercase or not? Declaring inside or not?

Answer (score 0):

indeed each statement inside a function runs every time the function is executed. Whether this affects performance depends on how expensive the statement is and how often the function is actually executed.

To find out how expensive a simple statement is you can use the python standard lib [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer.timeit).

If not too expensive, I would advise declaring variables inside the function if they are only meaningful within the function.